# use Globalize.localize() in razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization

i am using Globalize.localize for handling multiple language in my project.
i am using globlaization version 0.x.
i have already tried in my javascript file for changing language :

```
dataField: "Username",
                editorType: "dxTextBox",
                label: { text: Globalize.localize('user-name') },
                validationRules: [{
                    type: "required",
                } .
```

but when i using `Globalize.localize('user-name')` in my html file(Razor) its not working . how can i change language in html file like i the example that i use in javascript file

Comment: I don't see anything about `localize()` method in `Globalize.js`, could you tell is it a custom method or something else? Also check here for localization in Devextreme: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/Widgets/Common/UI_Widgets/Localization_-_Use_Globalize/.

Comment: i do try step by step localization from the link above you gave me before . but i have this error :Globalize.formatMessage is not a function @TetsuyaYamamoto